# Spring web access the original file Path of a multipart FilePart

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

We have a Spring WebFlux application, with an endpoint that receives multipart data, including a file. After the upload we have to send the file to an antivirus scanner, installed on the same server as the WebFlux application.

The only solution we found up to now is to use `FilePart#transferTo(dest)` which creates a copy of the file.
The actual `Path` of the file as created by Spring framework is stored inside the class `DefaultParts` but it's private, and no method allows any access to it.

Is there any other solution that will allow us to access the `Path` of the file without creating a copy of it ?

Currently, we did consider using reflection to access the field, but it's not something we are happy with:

```java
return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            final Object content = FieldUtils.readField(filePart, "content", true);
            return (Path) FieldUtils.readField(content, "file", true);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

##### Application

A webflux application, with an endpoint receiving multipart data, including a file. The application is based on Spring boot 3.1.5

#### Goal

Find the `Path` of the file created on the filesystem, to use it afterward

#### Original code

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public Mono<Void> upload(@RequestParam String token, @RequestPart Mono<FilePart> file) {
    // Here, there is no way to access to the Path of the file argument once 
    // received & created on the filesystem by Spring
    // Only solution is to create a copy with the FilePart#transferTo() method
}
```

### Actual Solution

Spring 6.x introduces `PartEvent` ([documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/multipart/PartEvent.html)) that allows receiving files from a multipart request by chunk, preventing Spring from creating the whole file on the filesystem by itself. Instead, it is our code that creates the file on the filesystem, and thus we have full control on the Path and we reach our goal to have only one copy of the file on the filesystem.

##### Code

```java
// Note: parts of the code are omitted for brevity
// The class PartEvent has a complete code example in its javadoc
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public Mono<Void> upload2(@RequestParam String token, @RequestBody Flux<PartEvent> allPartsEvents) {

    return allPartsEvents.windowUntil(PartEvent::isLast)
        .concatMap(p -> p.switchOnFirst((signal, partEvents) -> {
            PartEvent event = signal.get();
            if (event instanceof FilePartEvent fileEvent) {
                // Here we create the file on the filesystem
                return FileUtils.createTempFile(fileEvent.filename())
                    .flatMap(path ->
                        // And here we write in the file following the Flux<PartEvent> we are receiving
                        DataBufferUtils.write(partEvents.map(PartEvent::content), path,
                            StandardOpenOption.CREATE));
            }

            return Mono.empty();
        })).then();
}
```